# Unable to import Undirected Graph in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am unable to import undirected graph. Neo4J Developer Manual v3.1 suggests that undirected relation can be created. But I get directed relation.
Can anyone please suggest me on how to write a CQL query for undirected graph. Following is the actual query on which I want to work upon.

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///E:/HVR_1.csv" as row 
MERGE (u:Port1 {id: toInt(row[0])}) 
MERGE (t:Port1 {id: toInt(row[1])}) 
MERGE (u)-[:LinkTo]-(t)
```

Please do help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All relationships in Neo4j are directed. While there is a concept of undirected relationships, where the direction is not specified, it really means "I don't care about direction". A relationship created with with an unspecified direction will choose some direction for that relationship.

When matching on an undirected relationship (either through a MATCH, or a MERGE on a relationship that should exist), it will match on the relationship specified no matter how it's directed.

So in your case, a :LinkTo relationship is created in some direction. When using MATCH or MERGE later, as long as you keep the relationship undirected in your query, it will match on whatever relationship exists no matter the direction.

In summary, all an undirected relationship is, or ever needs to be, is some relationship where the direction (both as it is in the graph, and as specified in your queries) doesn't matter.